# Kali linux login

Tags: kali-linux, login

I got Kali Linux installed on my flash drive it stick in boot up at the log in. I've done the `control,alt,f3` to try, and log in I can type username in, but when it asks for the password it won't even let me type anything in. I press buttons and nothing goes into the password. I’ve been looking and looking and I can't find anything. How can I log in?

Comment: Unix systems in general usually does not echo back anything at password prompts. This is normal. It accepts the input, but won't show you what (or even that) you're typing.

Comment: So it will continuesly leave it blank when typing?

Comment: Kind of weird that you're using Kali and don't know this. But yes.

Comment: Correct. This way, someone watching your screen can't guess how long your password is (unless you have a noisy keyboard).

Comment: I'll go ahead and save you from future problems: Probably don't use Kali if you don't know password prompts on Linux systems show nothing when typing your password

Comment: If you don't have knowledge of linux. I will recommend you to install ubuntu instead of Kali.

Comment: If you know this little about Linux-based systems PLEASE DO NOT START WITH KALI. Try Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora or many of the other simpler distrubitions. You'll learn all sorts of bad habits with Kali. Really.

Answer (score 0):

The login password prompt (and most other password prompts) on Unix systems don't generally echo anything back when you're typing at them.

The system accepts the input but will not show anything while you are typing.

Speculation: If the password prompt returned `*` for each typed character, someone watching you would see the length of your password, which would potentially make it easier to guess/crack.